# No pattern match for Seq[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, seq, extractor

```
def example1(sss:Seq[Seq[String]]) = sss match {
  case Seq(a, b) :+ Seq(c, d) :+ tail => true
}

val res1 = example1(Seq(Seq("a", "b"), Seq("c","d")))
// scala.MatchError: List(List(a, b), List(c, d))
```

Well I have a workaround, which is to use

```
case Seq(Seq(a, b), Seq(c, d), _*) => true
```

Can anyone explain why the first doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong extractor! `:+` implies that the first part is part of the (outer) Seq, hence `a` and `b` are of type `Seq[String]` rather than `String`, while the second part `Seq(c,d)`, and `tail` are treated as elements, so `c` and `d` are in fact `String`.

Normally this wouldn't type check, but in the case where the element type is a `Seq`, it does. However if you assume `a` and `b` are `String`, and try to treat them as such, the type checker might complain, causing more confusion.

The correct extractor is `+:`. The colon goes on the side of the sequence, and the plus on the side of the element. Hence

```
  case Seq(a, b) +: Seq(c, d) +: tail => true
```

matches as expected.